# Termination of remote Akka Actor System

Tags: akka, actor

I have a problem, where the second invocation of my program gives unpredictable behaviour.

I am trying to ensure a graceful shutdown of an akka-remoting application.

I have two actor systems, a local actor system and a remote actor system.

The local actor system

1. creates two actors, one on the local system and one on the remote
2. shuts himself down

I first start the remote actor system and then run the local actor system.

When i run this the first time, everything is okay, and the local actor system shuts down (the remote is still up). But if i run this a second time (without restarting the remote system), the behaviour is different and the two actor systems start heart beating. **The local does not shut down.**

The minimal code to replicate the behaviour is below

**Local Actor System**

```
object ActorAsSink_7  extends App {
    val system = ActorSystem("system")
    val localActor = system.actorOf(MyActor_4.props)
    val remoteActor = system.actorOf(MyActor_4.props, "remote_agent") 
    localActor ! PoisonPill
}
```

**Remote Actor System**

```
object RemoteActorSystem  extends App {

  import system.dispatcher
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("remote-actorsystem")

  // actors in this actor system are created remotely

  println("hello.. remote agent is up")

}
```

This is part of a much larger code base, and this is the minimal i was able to find to replicate the issue.

Why is my local actor system behaving differently and not shutting down in the second invocation?

The local actor does the following

```
object MyActor_4 {
  val props = Props[MyActor_4]
}

class MyActor_4 extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = { case x: Any  => log.error("unexpected message in reaper: " + x)  }
  override def postStop = { println ("shutting down...") ;  context.system.terminate(); }  
}
```

Remoting is working fine, but for this shutdown issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding below code line would not stop remoteActor.

```
    localActor ! PoisonPill
```

Because PoisonPill stops the sender actor and all its child actors.
 Here remoteActor is not a child actor of localActor.
could you share the logs where both actors of local actor system stop in first run ?

Comment: To shutdown the ActorSystem you can do this way `system.shutdown`
To stop the localActor & remoteActor without stopping the ActorSystem            `system.actorSelection("/user/*") ! PoisonPill` 
Can check this for more details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356986/stop-all-actors-in-a-system-without-shutting-down-the-system-itself